# Dynamic date element in URL

Tags: jquery, html, sharepoint

I am trying to create a div for a link to a SharePoint calendar that will always go to the next month (e.g., it is currently November but I want to be directed to December). I know that the URL can be appended to be directed to a specific date, but the goal is to not have to change the code every month.

Here is what I have so far (hard-coded specific date):

```
<a href=" http://url.aspx?CalendarDate=12/1/2015&CalendarPeriod=month">
<div style="cursor: hand; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 1000; width: 415px; height: 515px;
background-color: white; z-index: 2; opacity: 0.4; filter: alpha(opacity = 0)">
</div>
</a>
```

How can I create a more dynamic URL that will know the current/next month? I cannot figure out how to concatenate `getMonth()` and `getFullYear()` or any other such methods into the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenation with the `getMonth()` and `getFullYear()` into the URL is not difficult. You just have to use the `+` operator in the URL string.

```
var year = new Date().getFullYear();
var month = new Date().getMonth() + 2;

if(new Date().getMonth() == 11) {
    // if already December, go to January and increment the year
    month = 1;
    year++;
}    

document.getElementById("link").href = "http://url.aspx?CalendarDate=" + month + "/1/" + year + "&CalendarPeriod=month";
```

Note: `getMonth()` returns a number from 0-11 (not 1-12) -- This is why there is the `+2` when `+1` seems correct.

See a [working example on JSFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/gqhstc3a/1).

Comment: I see how your example works, but when I integrate the javascript into the HTML with a <script>, I can't get the <a id="link"> to create the link on the div. The div is created, but there is no link to click on.

Comment: I made some changes and it works perfectly now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jonathan, here is the final product:

```
<a id="link">
<script>
var year = new Date().getFullYear();
var month = new Date().getMonth() + 2;



if(new Date().getMonth() == 11) {
// if already December, go to January and increment the year
month = 1;
year++;
}   

document.getElementById("link").href = "http://url.aspx?CalendarDate=" + month + "/1/" + year + "&CalendarPeriod=month";

</script>  
<div style="cursor: hand; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 580; width:         415px; height: 515px;
background-color: white; z-index: 2; opacity: 0.4; filter: alpha(opacity = 0)">
</div>
</a>
```